# In a DAG, what is the name of the process replacing no branch path with a single vertex

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics, dag

In my work, I meet a process for DAG, and need to explain it in my report. So, I would like to know the name of the process.

The process is very simple. The vertices of degree two except roots and leaves are replaced to the new edge between the parent and child vertices.

[image]

This process is almost the same to what [this library](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/simplify-dag) achieves.

Comment: I know the word [Smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing), not sure how standard it is

Comment: This is similar to edge contraction.